# Solving 2-degree equations in 3 variables.

Tags: systems-of-equations

We are given 3 equations:

$x^2+\sqrt3 xy + y^2 = 25$

$y^2 + z^2 = 9$

$x^2 +xz+ z^2 = 16$.

$x,y,z$ are positive real numbers.

Then we have to find value of $xy + 2yz + \sqrt3 xz$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried AM GM , other then that I have no idea how to go further

Comment: Why are you applying AM-GM and how?

Comment: I saw there are positive real number so I thought of that, applied on x^2 and y^2 to get in terms  xy and similarly for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have $$\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: \left\{\begin{aligned} x^{2}+\sqrt{3} xy + y^2 &=& 25\\
y^{2} + z^{2} &=& 9\\
x^{2} +xz+ z^{2} &=& 16  \end{aligned} \right.$$ if, and only if, $$ \forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: \left\{\begin{aligned} x^{2}+\sqrt{3} xy + y^2 &=& \color{blue}{5}^{2}\\
y^{2} + z^{2} &=& \color{blue}{3}^{2}\\
x^{2} +xz+ z^{2} &=& \color{blue}{4}^{2}  \end{aligned} \right. $$
Now, we can approach this problem as *an algebraic geometry problem*. Indeed, consider a triangle $\bigtriangleup XYZ$ with side lengths $3,4,5$ and draw a point $P$ inside the triangle such that $XP=x$, $YP=y$, and $ZP=z$. Now, you can considerer he equations in the context of the *law of cosines*.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: The eqns helped me to find XPZ=150°, XPY=120°, ZPY=90° .not able to proceed further.

Comment: +1 from me as it was good enough hint for the OP to continue from and solve.

Comment: What would you do if it was $26$ instead of $25$ ?

Comment: where can I Find more about 'algebraic geometry ' techqniues? as shown above

Answer (score 5):

Based on system of equations being sides of a right angled triangle and a point P
inside the triangle such that -

$\angle BPC = 90^0, \angle APC = 150^0, \angle APB = 120^0 $
and, $AP = x, CP = y, BP = z$

We know area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2} \times$ length of side 1 $\times$ length of side 2 $\times \sin \theta$
*where $\theta$ is the angle between side 1 and side 2.*

Now sum of area, $\triangle APC + \triangle BPC + \triangle APB = \triangle XYZ$

$\frac{1}{2}(xy\sin150^0 + yz\sin90^0 + xz\sin 120^0) = \frac{1}{2} \times 3 \times 4$

$xy \times \frac{1}{2} + yz + xz \times \frac{\sqrt3}{2} = 12$

$xy + 2yz + \sqrt3 xz = 24$

Comment: nice solution because it gets to the value without finding x, y, z separately!

Comment: @prags yes if we try and find x, y, z first then it is similar to solving the system of equations, avoiding which was the idea in the first place.

Comment: Good; I will look at this some more.

Comment: What would you do if it was $26$ instead of $25$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici of course you are right and I am aware. For $26$, at least it is still a triangle. There will be set of values when this cannot be expressed as squares of the sides of a triangle. So of course it does not apply then. But given it applies here, given the way question is asked, given the expression for which value has been asked, this is an efficient way to solve this specific problem.

Comment: I am just kidding. I don't know if you look at my edit. I found the work amazing (even if tedious). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No I was not following this question anymore. I wish there was a way to notify changes (at least certain types of changes, new answers) to a post where we answered in the past, bookmarked or showed interest. I will definitely check when I get time.

Answer (score 3):

*Just for the fun !*

Using algebra, you can entirely solve the problem. Let
$$X=x^2 \qquad Y=y^2 \qquad Z=z^2 \qquad a= xy \qquad b=xz$$So, the equations are now
$$X+\sqrt{3} a+Y=25 \tag 1$$
$$Y+Z=9\tag 2$$
$$ X +b+ Z=16\tag 3$$
$$a^2=XY\tag 4$$
$$b^2=XZ\tag 5$$

Using $(1)$,$(2)$ and $(3)$ which are linear equations, we have
$$X=-\frac{\sqrt{3} a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}+16\qquad Y=-\frac{\sqrt{3} a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+9\qquad Z=\frac{\sqrt{3} a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}$$ Replacing, equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ become
$$-a^2-50 \sqrt{3} a-b^2+14 b+576=0 \tag 6$$
$$-3 a^2+32 \sqrt{3} a-3 b^2-32 b=0\tag 7$$ Using $(7)$
$$b=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{-9 a^2+96 \sqrt{3} a+256}-16\right)$$ Plug in $(6)$ to get
$$74 \sqrt{-9 a^2+96 \sqrt{3} a+256}-546 \sqrt{3} a+4000=0$$

One squaring step to get

$$a=\frac{96 \left(148+177 \sqrt{3}\right)}{6553}\qquad \implies \qquad   b=\frac{384 \left(91 \sqrt{3}-72\right)}{6553}$$
$$x=32 \sqrt{\frac{91-24 \sqrt{3}}{6553}}\qquad y=3 \sqrt{\frac{2185+1152 \sqrt{3}}{6553}} \qquad z=12 \sqrt{\frac{3 \left(91-24 \sqrt{3}\right)}{6553}}$$

Now, you can compute the value of any function $f(x,y,z)$.

**Edit**

In comments, @WillJagy reported difficulties for the more general case where the equations would be
$$X+\alpha\, a+Y=\beta \tag 1$$
$$Y+Z=9\tag 2$$
$$ X +b+ Z=16\tag 3$$
$$a^2=XY\tag 4$$
$$b^2=XZ\tag 5$$

Repeating the same steps, I have
$$X=x^2=-\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{-3 a^2 \alpha ^2+6 a \alpha  \beta -54 a \alpha -3 \beta
   ^2+54 \beta +781}-\frac{a \alpha }{2}+\frac{\beta }{2}+\frac{37}{6}$$
$$Y=y^2=+ \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{-3 a^2 \alpha ^2+6 a \alpha  \beta -54 a \alpha -3 \beta ^2+54
   \beta +781}-\frac{a \alpha }{2}+\frac{\beta }{2}-\frac{37}{6}$$
$$Z=z^2=-\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{-3 a^2 \alpha ^2+6 a \alpha  \beta -54 a \alpha -3 \beta
   ^2+54 \beta +781}+\frac{a \alpha }{2}-\frac{\beta }{2}+\frac{91}{6}$$
The problem now is that the last equation in $a$ is a quartic and no more a quadratic.

To reduce it to a cubic would require
$$16 \left(\alpha ^2-3\right)^2 \implies \alpha=\pm \sqrt 3$$ which in fact reduces the last equation to a quadratic the solution of which being
$$a=\frac{(\beta +7) \left(\sqrt{3} \left(4 \beta ^2-55 \beta
   -63\right)+\sqrt{(49-\beta ) (\beta -1)}\right)}{2 \left(12 \beta ^2-54 \beta +403\right)}$$  So, we have the analytical solution for any $1\leq \beta \leq 49$, the variables $(x,y,z)$ being non-negative in this range.

Comment: Nice. Can we also use complex numbers to solve these eqn.z=rcosx+irsinx. Equating real and img part.

Comment: @Dev. There are many things we could do. Why don't you post an answer ? It would be interesting. Cheers :-)

Comment: Claude, I have been trying to solve the general system with symbols, say $x^2 - a_{12}xy + y^2 = d_{12}^2$ for $x,y$  then the other two pairs. No luck yet.

Comment: @WillJagy. If we just change the first equation as $x^2+\alpha xy+y^2=\beta$ and keep the other two as they are, I did not find any problem before the last step (computing $a$). This effective leads to a monstrous quadratic (I have the explicit solutions). But the problem is that we need the positive root. I shall make an edit. Cheers.

Comment: Claude, thank you so much.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici this looks great. Btw the triangle method that I used will also work for $\beta \lt 49$ (basically as long as it is a triangle, we can apply cosine law and add up individual areas and equate the same way as we did for $25$. It will of course be more tedious. Only if it goes to $49$ or above, the triangle method would not work.

Comment: @WillJagy. Good to know ! May I confess that I am very, very bad with triangles. What is interesting (just try it) is to plot the goal function with respect to $\beta$. Cheers and have a nice day (I am going to bed now). Thanks to you, I had fun.

Comment: Sweet Dreams...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an accurate picture. Draw in some extra lines......

[image]

Comment: Yes that what I got but how we will proceed now and find xy+2yz+√3xz from this ?

Comment: +1 from me as it was good enough hint for the OP to continue from and solve.

Comment: @MathLover thanks. I wondered, last night, if an argument with Law of Sines  and Law of Cosines might work, introducing one or two of the remaining angles as new vertices. I still do not know. It is very likely, perhaps I will examine the other answers in detail, that using the coordinate axes, the length 3 in the traditional $x$ direction and the 4 in the traditional $y$ direction.

Comment: @WillJagy please see my solution which is based on it.

Comment: You are right ! The last equation is a quartic in $a$.

Comment: Have a look at my edit (if you have time to waste). We meed $\alpha=\pm\sqrt 3$ to reduce from quartic to quadratic. Now, your turn : solve the problem changing $25$ to wathever you want using your method. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Thank you for looking into the matter. In my first try, I put some things into gp-pari, then tried to make sense of that. Later, it beame far too hot in my apartment to think at all, 92 Fahrenheit is about 33 Celsius ( I am on the upper floor, the (flat) roof remains hot after dark). Now, early morning, it is 81 Fahrenheit, about 27 Celsius, I may be able to think straight for a while.

Comment: @WillJagy. What is amaring is that it is only for $\beta=25$ that the expression is an integer. Morover, $24$ is the maximum value of the function. Knowing it, it becomes a piece of cake. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Given a triangle with sides $l_1,l_2,l_3$ we have

$$
\cases{
l_1^2=l_2^2+l_3^2-2l_2l_3\cos\theta_1\\
l_2^2=l_1^2+l_3^2-2l_1l_3\cos\theta_2\\
l_2^2=l_1^2+l_2^2-2l_1 l_2\cos\theta_3
}
$$

then making $l_1=x,l_2=y,l_3=z$

$$
\cases{
2\cos\theta_1=0\\
2\cos\theta_2=-1\\
2\cos\theta_3=-\sqrt{3}
}
$$

It is a rectangle. Etc.