# Converting a number theory question into involving vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

> $p,q,r \in \mathbb{R^+}$ $$p^2 +q^2 = 9 $$ $$q^2+qr+r^2=16$$ $$ p^2 + \sqrt{3} pr +r^2 =25$$
> Find $2pq + pr+ \sqrt{3} pr$

***My attempt:***

I tried to interpret this equation as one involving vector dot products by the steps presented below:

Let $\vec{p}$ , $ \vec{q}$ and $ \vec{r}$ be vectors, then the first identity suggests that $ \vec{p} \perp \vec{q}$ as we would see if we compare the formula of dot products:

if, $$ |p+q|^2 = 9 $$

$ \implies  p \cdot q = 0 $ and since they are non zero vectors , the vectors must necessarily be perpendicular. Similarly, we find that $ \vec{q} $ and $ \vec{r}$ are angled at $ \frac{\pi}{3}$ degrees and finally $ \vec{p} $ and $ \vec{r}$ are at an angle of $ \frac{\pi}{6}$ degrees.

So, what we want to find is this:

$$ F(p,q,r) = 2 |p| |q| + |p| |r| + \sqrt{3} |p| |r|$$

One last thing which I thought of doing is writing $ \vec{r}$  in the basis of $ \vec{p}$ and $ \vec{q}$ since they are orthogonal, but, I'm worried that $ \vec{r}$ may not be in the plane defined by $ \vec{p}$ and $ \vec{q}$. Anyways I have shown the decomposition below:

$$ \vec{r} =  \frac{ \vec{r} \cdot \vec{p} }{ |p| } \vec{p} + \frac{ \vec{r} \cdot \vec{q} }{|q| } \vec{q}$$

---

Not sure how to proceed next/ if it is even solvable by this method. Appreciate any help given.

---

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, I'll point out the reference if I find it

Comment: here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815573/solving-2-degree-equations-in-3-variables. Maybe it can help you

Comment: Yeah that post definitely does discuss the problem statement but not really in my method. I'll see if I can devise a way to finish from my starting referring that.

Comment: Can you explain better how $\vec{p}$ is defined?

Comment: basically that original problem statement, I interpretted to be speaking of the magnitudes of the vectors. The new one which I wrote down, is the actual vector itself.

Comment: And, secondly, I don't understand why this was closed as I was asking help for a different method to solve the question